# Deallocate all memory used by my iOS application if application crash unexpectedly?

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash

I am beginner in iPhone App Development. Sorry for silly questions.

Consider a case that if my application crashes without any warning then all the memory allocated by my application will be freed automatically by iOS or is it stay as it is?

If not released by iOS then how and where can I release them?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186056/how-free-memory-imediately-in-ios for your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do if your application crashed. By the time app crash, system will destroy allocated memory the particular app. When application start again, there is no allocated memory, and your application will start fresh.

You should manage your memory in your application properly, 
see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186056/how-free-memory-imediately-in-ios) or [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/)

or you may try [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), see this [tutorial](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes any decent OS frees all memory and releases many other resources like file handles used by a program when that program terminates. It doesn't matter how the program terminates. One important thing to note is that the OS reclaims the memory without releasing/destroying your objects. So any code that normally would be run automatically when an object is cleanly released won't be called when the OS reclaims the memory on program termination.

Answer (score 0):

you  will have to release your global(decalred in .h file) objects in dealloc method that is

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   //release here
}
```

your private or instance objects you  can release after it is used.

Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to began working in ARC (Automatic Reference Count)  also it works in iOS4 & iOS5