# Can I count up whole of views to check performance?

Tags: ios, performance

Memory use and cpu time can be available like below.

[Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)

And also i'd like to know the number of views to check performance? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself. call countViewsInApp. thx.

```
+ (int)countViewsInApp {
    int num = 0;

    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        for (UIView *aView in [window subviews]) {
            num++; // parent
            num += [self countSubviews:aView];
        }
    }

    return num;
}

+ (int)countSubviews:(UIView *)view {
    int num = 0;

    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        num++;
        if ([[subview subviews] count] > 0) {
            num += [self countSubviews:subview];
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
- (NSUInteger *)countSubviewsInViewСonsideringView:(UIView *)view {
   NSUInteger subviewsCount = 1; // the current view
   for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
      subviewsCount += [self countSubviewsInViewСonsideringView:subView]
   }
   return subviewsCount;
}
```

somewhere in code:

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
NSUInteger count = [self countSubviewsInViewСonsideringView:window];
```

Comment: Ur answer is very near :)