# How to display memory usage of my application in my iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, ios7.1

I want to display my my app memory usage in my iphone application
Some where like Navigation Bar or adding a subview to UIWindow , so it will be display in all the screens and display the current memory usage

Comment: Are you asking about your app live memory (running memory) or app document folder memory on device?

Answer (score 1):

From: [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)

```
#import <mach/mach.h>

// ...

void report_memory(void) {
  struct task_basic_info info;
  mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
  kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                 TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                 (task_info_t)&info,
                                 &size);
  if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
  }
}
```