# Shared memory used by my app

Tags: ios, memory

Is there a way to get the amount of shared memory that is in use by my app?
I need to get the amount of shared memory in use during runtime and use it in my app so instrumentation won't do the trick for me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)

Comment: Nope, that link extracts the resident memory (which I already used) but it doesn't help regarding the shared memory alone