# Size of memory allocated by applicaton on iPhone

Tags: ios, memory-management

Is there a way to know the size of memory space allocated by an application on iPhone or iPad via objective-c code? This is just to know how much memory my application is allocating space in RAM during run time.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone

Comment: Xcode displays this while the app is running.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Instruments by apple themselves if you don't want to put extra code in your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

This is just an example of doing this without the code.

Comment: I don't need to use instruments, I could see it by using the duplicate post