# Why MKMapKit takes tons of memory

Tags: ios, xcode6, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have made an app in which there is a functionality of `Map`.

Whenever my Controller opens the screen that contains the map the memory usage directly hikes to `180MB` from `45mb`.

I have just used an `MKMap` and set its `delegate`.

Whats the problem that is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the memory usage in actual device. I had the same problem in simulator, but device showed actual usage. I think its a simulator bug.

Comment: i am unable to check the usage on device..as i don't have development provisioning

Comment: @Sid Whenever you try it on device, it will not be a problem. No need to worry. Please upvote if my answer helped you

Comment: when i connect my device and select **Product->Profile** and start recording then i get error message that i am misising developer profile...is their any other way to test.

Comment: @Sid You need a paid developer account to test apps on devices. I doubt that you cannot test it without a provisioning profile.

Comment: I have adhoc onces only

Comment: You can do one thing. You can print the memory usage and check it in device log (**Window > Devices**). Follow this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone