# How to programmatically get free / used memory usage using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there an API to get free or used memory for iOS iPhone?

I can get the total memory size in bytes from NSProcessInfo.

```
[ NSProcessInfo processInfo ].physicalMemory;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)

Comment: A simple web search could help you.